# How calculate bearing between latitudes and longitudes with 1 point

Tags: javascript, php

I have a formula bearing with php function :

```
function bearing($lat1, $long1, $lat2, $long2){

$bearingradians = atan2(asin($long1-$long2)*cos($lat2),
cos($lat1)*sin($lat2) - sin($lat1)*cos($lat2)*cos($long1-$long2));
$bearingdegrees = rad2deg($bearing);

return $bearingdegrees
}
```

with 
$Long1     = 106.0543333,

$Lat1      = -5.8836667

I'm confused, how do I get $Lat2 & $Long2? so that I can enter into the formula.

Comment: This formula can be used when you have two points. Otherwise not. Simple. What are you so confused about.

Answer (score 0):

A bearing is essentially your direction of travel.  A single point only tells you a single location.  It would be like asking someone "Are you driving north?" and they tell you what street address they are passing.  The street address might tell you where they are but it doesn't tell you what direction they are driving.  But if they told you the street address they were passing 10 minutes ago and the street address they are passing right now you could calculate what general direction they were heading that is essentially their bearing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)